# break away from a controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My question is if there is a rails equivalent to 'breaking' away from a controller action such as

```
def new
    if some_confirmation
        do_stuff
        break #I know this only breaks out of a loop but I want it to break out of the action. is this possible?
    end
    do_some_other_stuff_which_it_should_not_reach_after_breaking
end
```

Also this raises the question if I'm doing something wrong and shouldn't be rather doing it with a `before_filter`

Also last question, is it better to enclose everything in a 'if-else'-statement in such definitions (not necessarily controller actions but also normal definitions) or do it like the way I intend to do up there ^?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is to use `return`. Controller actions are just methods and `return` is how you return early from a method. There's nothing wrong with doing this and you should feel free to do so as needed.

You can use `before_filter`s (which has been renamed to `before_action` in Rails 4), as you mention, but I recommend only doing this if every method in the controller requires the condition. Otherwise, you end up with a huge list of `before_action`s at the top that you have to keep in mind (or be surprised by) while reading the actions later; and it gets especially confusing if you have to keep in mind which ones apply and which ones don't for which actions!

Whether or not if-else statements are preferred is a bit of an opinion... but, inspired by Avdi Grimm's excellent book [*Confident Ruby*](http://www.confidentruby.com/), I recommend to do as you've done here... what you've set up is essentially a guard clause whereby you take care of exiting the method early up front, and then you get into the actual meat of the method. In *Confident Ruby*, Avdi Grimm talks about breaking methods up into logical parts to tell a coherent story that doesn't force readers to keep track of various states throughout the life of the method. Using an if-else statement tends to force readers to keep track of state, whereas using guard clauses allows you to quickly identify conditions to leave the method via and then forget about them so you can focus on the actual purpose of the method.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed and also very informative!